# Extend SharePoint 2010 web application to use https(SSL)

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, ssl, https

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application which uses Claims based authentication with NTLM and the site is published to TMG. After completing this process a few days later we installed SSL certificates on SharePoint server and I have configured https on IIS and I have also added AAM in central admin with default zone using 'http' and internet zone using 'https'.

Do I need to extend the web application(in central admin) to use https or is it enough to provide the URL in AAM?

Do I need to import the certificate in to SharePoint (Central admin -> security -> Manage trust)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you changed the public URL in AAM & configured the IIS website to use SSL it will work without extending to a new website. However, whenever you will add a new webserver SharePoint will configure the original IIS settings that it knows about. That's why it's so important to specify the right public url & host header upon creation of a new web application. So if you still have the freedom to do so, you can unextend the web application and then extend it again with the correct settings. You will still need to add the certificate in IIS yourself however.

You don't need to import the certificates to SharePoint. That functionality is to configure trusts with other farms or authentication providers.